# How to change only the diagonal elements of a 2D list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

So I am trying to create an NxN 2D array and then change its diagonal elemets to 1. Here is my code:

```
arr=[1,1,1,2,2,2]
table=[[0]*len(arr)]*len(arr)
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    table[i][i]=1
print(table)
```

However, whenever I run this code, I get this output:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I am looking to get this:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I have been staring at my code for hours and I cannot figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting thing about this is that you are really only editing *one* list in the `for` loop, but there are just five pointers to that list. (In this case, the list would be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.) You can see this by printing the id of each list in `table` by using `id()`:

```py
>>> for t in table:
        print(id(t))

2236544254464
2236544254464
2236544254464
2236544254464
2236544254464
2236544254464
```

Your numbers are likely different than mine, but they are all the *same* number, nevertheless. You also can see that the edits to one list are applied to the others in `table` by putting a `print(table)` statement after each index assignment statement.

So in order to 'fix' this, I would recommend using list comprehension instead. For example:

```py
table = [[0]*len(arr) for _ in range(len(arr))]
```

If you checkout the ids of each list:

```py
>>> for t in table:
    print(id(t))

    
2236544617664
2236544616064
2236544616320
2236544615872
2236544618368
2236544622720
```

Since they are different, you can now use the method for changing only the diagonals:

```py
>>> for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        table[i][i]=1

>>> table
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your 2D "array" contains 6 lists which are the same list. Changes to any of those lists will also be reflected in the other lists. Consider this:

```
>>> l = [0] * 6
>>> x = [l]
>>> l[0] = 1
>>> l
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> x
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> x = [l, l, l]
>>> x
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> x[-1][-1] = 100
>>> x
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100]]
```

This is because the list `x` contains the list `l`, so any changes to `l` are also seen through the reference to the same list in `x`.

The problem is when multiplying mutable objects because it creates multiple *references* to the same mutable object.

You should initialise your table like this:

```
table = [[0 for j in range(len(arr))] for i in range(len(arr))]
```

or

```
table = [[0] * len(arr) for i in range(len(arr))]
```

which, despite the use of multiplication, works because each list is different.

Comment: so if i initialize an array like [0]*len(arr) and change any one element, it will change all the elements?

Comment: @fahadhub: not in that case. I have added some explanation to the answer. The problem is that multiplying objects creates multiple _references_ to them, not new instances of the object. In the case of `[0]*6` you get a list containing 6 references to the same `0` object, but, because integers are immutable (can't be changed), when you do change one of them you end up with a _new_ object. But lists are mutable so you do not get a new list object when you change one of its elements, so the change is visible through all references to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your table and populate it simultaneously in nested loops:

```
arr=[1,1,1,2,2,2]

table = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    table.append([0]*len(arr))
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        if i == j:
            table[i][j] = 1

print(table)
#[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.
Try to use numpy to avoid list trap:

```py
import numpy as np
org_row = [0]*5
l = [org_row]*5
x = np.array(l, np.int32)
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i][i]=1
print(x)
```

output>:

```sh
output>
[[1 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 1]]
```