# What is the efficient way to extract diagonal "blocks" in a 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python, arrays, diagonal

I have a 2-dimensional list of random values. I want to take the parts marked by 1 and 0 and separate them to different 1 dimensional lists. Ones only occur diagonally.

I have a list like this.

`[[1 if (i // 3) * 3 <= j < (i // 3) * 3 + 3 else 0 for i in range(9)] for j in range(9)]`

```py
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

The actual matrix can have thousands of rows and columns. The rows and columns of 1 blocks can be 10 or 20 or 30. I want to separate 1 and 0 in this list and make a 1 dimensional list for each of them.

```py
list1 = [1,1,1,....,1,1,1]
list0 = [0,0,0,....,0,0,0]
```

I managed to write a code like this.

```py
diag = [costest[i][j] for i in range(len(costest)) for j in range(len(costest)) if (i // 3) * 3 <= j < (i // 3) * 3 + 3]
nondiag = [costest[i][j] for i in range(len(costest)) for j in range(len(costest)) if (i // 3) * 3 > j or j >= (i // 3) * 3 + 3]
```

This works but I suspect there might be a better solution. This looks dirty. I googled with the keywords "python 2 dimensional list diagonal part only" but all they showed was a page like this [python 3.x - How to change only the diagonal elements of a 2D list? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593157/how-to-change-only-the-diagonal-elements-of-a-2d-list)

Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: It's not really clear from the question, but do the ones *only* occur on the diagonals. In other words, from your example, it doesn't seem important that the ones are on the diagonal — is what you are trying to do different than just counting *all* the ones?